# Can I put the 7-kg hand luggage weight on to my suitcase weight so that I don't have to take hand luggage at all?

Tags: check-in

I'm going to Australia, and the check-in luggage is 23 kg, the hand luggage weight is 7 kg. Can I check-in 30 kg for my check-in luggage, and not take any hand luggage?

Comment: No. You will have to pay for the extra 7 kg luggage. (This is the norm, unless there is some exceptional rule in the terms of conditions of your ticket with the particular airline, for which you'll have to check on the airline website).

Comment: Remember, they have no way of linking your (overweight) luggage to someone boarding without any carry-on. What happens when you buy something in the terminal?

Comment: What airline are you travelling on, using what kind of fare? The checked baggage allowance (number and weight) can vary a lot, from 0 to 2 x 30 kg. Also, some airlines offer to check-in hand luggage for free on some flights (to free up space in overhead luggage racks), but this is more common on flights using single-aisle aircraft (so usually shorter flights).

Comment: For the record, it is probably not recommended to travel without hand luggage anyway. What if your case gets lost, or you want to take something on the plane?

Answer (score 5):

> Can I check - in 30kg for my check-in luggage, & not take any hand luggage?

No. Carry-on luggage and check-in luggage are managed differently and both are significant revenue streams for the airlines these days.

You can always ask, but there is 99%+ chance that they won't allow it charge you (considerably) for extra weight on your check-in bag.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on what airline you're flying as to whether there's an additional (usually high) charge for it, or whether it comes within your baggage allowance.

Some airlines include up to 30kg in your luggage allowance, however, **most allow only 23kg**, and some even less.  Anything more than your luggage allowance can incur an over-weight or excess baggage fee (not cheap!).  I believe the actual weight limit is around the 35kg mark, but I'm unaware of any airlines who include this in your ticketed allowance.

So, while you can probably put your 30kg into your checked luggage, you will need to check your particular airline and ticket rules as to whether it will cost you more.

Comment: The norm these days is 23kg economy and 30kg business for mainline carriers.

Comment: At least in Europe, the absolute maximum weight for checked luggage is 32kg based on labour protection regulations. If you travel with Lufthansa, business and first class tickets include at least two 32kg bags.

Comment: @Hilmar I have two international flights coming up (one US to NZ, one NZ to US).  One of them allows 23kg, the other 30kg.  Both are absolute cheapest back-of-the-plane economy (or the like), but on different airlines.

Comment: @Midavalo: than you got lucky. Anything more than 23 kg in economy is exceedingly rare these days, but not impossible.

Comment: @Hilmar Not lucky, there are plenty of airlines that offer 30kg or more for international economy.  See https://www.alternativeairlines.com/airlines-with-free-baggage.  I have no airline loyalty, I take whichever one suits me best, be it cost, luggage, time, or hopefully a combination .

Comment: @Midavalo: my apologies, you seem to be correct. It seems 23kg/50lbs is the standard for European and North American carriers but 30kg is often allowed by Asian carriers. Got to read the fine print :-)